# Can't connect/pair/discover BT keyboard to computer

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I've got me [one of these](http://us.hardware.info/reviews/3546/microsoft-sculpt-comfort-keyboard-review-split-spacebar) (Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Keyboard) but I can't find any way to make my computer see the device.

There's no button to press and I've put the receiver into an USB-port. All software is set up properly. The batteries are replaced. Twice! The store where I bought it tells me to talk to Microsoft. MS tells me to talk to the store. I feel like a ping-pong ball...

The strangest part is that I get the system to work as supposed to when I use my other keyboard (I've got me two exactly alike - one for the office and one for home usage). It's almost like the receiver I've got only works with the one keyboard and no other.

Of course, I've lost the receiver that came with the other keyboard. I thought I only needed on for both devices. Now I fear that it isn't the case...

Any hints on making my keyboard work with the "wrong" receiver? Or, ever better (since I'm surely going to lose the one I have right now too), how can I pair the stupid keyboard with the stupid **internal** BT receiver in my stupid computer?! Or am I myself just being stupid now?   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your keyboard is not a Bluetooth one.
It's wireless keyboard using 2.4GHz frequency and an USB adapter you're trying to use.
It should be plug and play: just plug the USB adapter to your USB and keyboard should work.

From what I see on MS site: only Windows 7 and Windows 8, both 32-bit and 64-bit are supported.
Older Windows editions would probably have some driver issues.

But... if you lost you adapter, I'm afraid you won't make it possible to run keyboard with any other one (unless it's the one from the exact same model).

Comment: Ah, that explains why my computer doesn't find the keyboard (since it's not BT). However, the other keyboard I mentioned is **exactly** the same model. I got two such keyboards because I wanted to have the same L&F at the office and at home. Any hints based on that?

Comment: Well, it should work but it seems that Microsoft included security code on the recievers to avoid disturbance in radio signals.
Have you tried turning off one keyboard, THEN turning on another and checking wheter it works on same reciever? If not, I must say I give up.